# Overcoming S3 Global Bucket Name Uniqueness Requirement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have separated our workloads for dev/test/prod etc into different accounts with AWS Orgnaizations. https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/

S3 requires bucket names to be unique globally. Because of this, we can't have an S3 Bucket, like 'OurS3Data' in each account. We could share one bucket between accounts, but we don't want to mix data between accounts.

What strategies are there to overcome this?

I considered using Route53/DNS to point to different buckets so 'OurS3Data.CompanyInternal.Com' always points to the account-specific bucket within the account - but we reference this bucket from code using multiple versions of the AWS SDK, and I'm pretty certain this is not supported.

We also considered storing a parameter in AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store, but this seems like a kludge https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html

Comment: One common approach is to use environment-specific suffixes, for example mybucket-prod, mybucket-dev, mybucket-qa. Your deployment tools should know which environment they are targeting and can append the relevant suffix. It also helps people recognize the purpose of bucket (or resource, more generally).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should be reading *all* external identifiers (bucket name, database name, whatever) from configuration. If you hardcode identifiers, it means that you have to rebuild your software to change anything.

There are many different ways to store this configuration. Parameter store is a good one, because it is tied to the account and also supports encrypted storage of secrets.

Some other approaches include an external configuration file in a known location on the deployment machine, environment variables (this is the preferred approach of the [12 factor app](https://12factor.net/config)), or different configuration service such as [Consul](https://www.consul.io/).

*Update*

Personally, I consider this a hack, but if you really don't have any other way to manage configuration ...

Name your buckets after your account ID and use `AWSSecurityTokenService.getCallerIdentity()` to retrieve that ID. If you don't want to use the actual ID as the bucket name, you could apply a hash function (but be aware that bucket names are limited to 63 characters).

Comment: I see what you're saying - we use DNS for just about everything so we can move stuff around without changing code. Just so happens DNS doesn't work for S3 in this case

Comment: @Dlongnecker - how do you store database credentials?

Comment: Touche, guest. We haven't hammered out our secret store quite yet, but clearly some config management is required and there's no reason 'S3BucketLocation' can't be one of them

Comment: I would agree, the account id thing is a hack - if I'm going to do that I might as well use some config management other than the parameter store.